# Трое из Простоквашино

Tags: грамматика

Может, кому-нибудь известно, почему название мультфильма "Простоквашино" не склонили? Ведь это литературный жанр.

Comment: У нас, к примеру, никогда не склоняли такие названия, несмотря на московские рекомендации: https://www.change.org/p/министр-культуры-рф-владимир-мединский-законодательно-запретить-склонение-названий-населённых-пунктов-петербурга-и-ленобласти

Comment: Да, Александр, я читал эту петицию. Но несклоняемость в повседневной речи допустима, так же как в газете. Но мультфильм - литературный жанр. Его создатель - Лев успенский.

Comment: "Петиция" абсолютно анекдотичная. Безграмотный человек требует увековечить свою безграмотность. И делает это совершенно безграмотно. Одно обращение чего стоит.

Comment: @Серж Только не Лев Успенский, а Эдуард.

Comment: Да,вы правы.Написал, потом,когда заметил,было поздно исправлять.

Comment: Авторы петиции - слишком большие либералы, предлагают штрафовать за неграмотную речь. Не штрафовать - расстреливать надо на месте :)

Comment: Ну, в таком случае нужно начинать с самих себя...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) **Русские и другие славянские топонимы на -ов(о), -ёв(о), -ев(о), -ин(о), -ын(о) традиционно склоняются**: телебашня в Останкине, дача в Переделкине, шоссе к Строгину́. Недаром помнит вся Россия про день Бородина́!

2) **Однако в XX веке сложилась тенденция к использованию несклоняемых вариантов.** Причины этого явления — в военном деле.  Ещё в царской армии во избежание путаницы был издан приказ употреблять в военных донесениях географические названия только в именительном падеже. В годы Великой Отечественной войны  и у гражданских людей стала появляться привычка не склонять названий населённых пунктов и других объектов местности: всё это время наши деды и прадеды читали в армейских приказах и **слышали во фронтовых сводках по радио только несклоняемые формы.**

3) Кандидат филологических наук, **главный редактор интернет-портала ГРАМОТА.РУ** Владимир Пахомов пишет:

Географические названия славянского происхождения, оканчивающиеся на -ово, -ево, -ино, -ыно, не склоняются в сочетании с родовым словом:  из деревни Простоквашино. Если же родового слова нет, то **нормативны оба варианта,** склоняемый (старый) и несклоняемый (новый): из Простоквашина и из Простоквашино. При этом склоняемый вариант соответствует строгой литературной норме (и рекомендуется, например, для речи дикторов).

[Склонение географических названий в русском языке | academic.ru](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ruwiki/1575843)

**Дополнение**

А вообще говоря, **не стоит подходить к проблеме формально и настаивать на одном варианте:** только склонять или только не склонять. Многое зависит от вида грамматической формы, от фонетической благозвучности.

Например, я просто не могу выговорить топонимы на ИН с ударным окончанием: я живу в Люблине или  Строгине, мне кажется, что это не название района, а какая-то "строгина", ведь суфикс ИН часто является суффиксом существительного. А вот **4-й микрорайон Братеева** звучит нормально, ведь при отсутствии склонения можно подумать, что это название микрорайона, а не района.

Comment: Да, я знаю это правило. Я склоняюсь к тому, что мультик тоже литературный жанр.

Comment: Серж, у автора был выбор, и он остановился на несклоняемом варианте, который хорош своей точностью: именно Простоквашино, а не Простоквашин.  А вот соблюдать строгую литературную форму в детской книжке он, по-видимому, не посчитал нужным: сначала была написана книга (1973), а потом снят мультфильм (1978).

Comment: "А начиналась история этого мультфильма в пионерском лагере, где тогда ещё молодой Эдуард Успенский подрабатывал библиотекарем. Интересных книг на всех детей не хватало, и начинающий писатель, чтобы развлечь малышей, стал придумывать как бы вечернюю сказку — приключения жителей деревни Простоквашино: славного Дяди Федора, преданного и честного Шарика, потрясающе умного, немного ироничного кота Матроскина и старенького почтальона Печкина. 
Книга была впервые опубликована в 1973 году". http://fishki.net/2203594-istorija-sozdanija-mulytfilyma-troe-iz-prostokvashino.html

Comment: Да, скорее вы правы: Простоквашино более точное название.

Comment: А что хорошего в такой точности? Зачем она нужна в детской книге?

Answer (score 2):

Я отвечу таки. Я не согласен с Успенским. *Простоквашино* должно склоняться. И даже Володя Пахомов ("грамота") это скрипя зубами подтверждает, избрав, правда, как опытный аппаратчик весьма размытую форму *"и рекомендуется, например, для речи дикторов"*. (см. Sibylla). То, что в том же источнике есть не менее авторитетные и не менее кандидаты, видимо, адептов несклонения не смущает. Но я процитирую.

> Кандидат филологических наук, член Городской межведомственной комиссии
>   по наименованию территориальных единиц, улиц и станций метрополитена
>   при Правительстве Москвы Р. А. Агеева излагает это правило иначе:
>
> «     Если перед географическим названием [среднего рода на -ино, -ево,
>   -ово] стоит так называемый родовой географический термин (а топоним грамматически является приложением), то может склоняться только этот
>   термин, а топоним склонять не обязательно: …в селе Дубнево или в селе
>   Дубневе (возможно, даже предпочтительнее первый вариант). Однако, если
>   топоним употребляется без родового географического термина, его
>   склонение по падежам обязательно. Таким образом, будем говорить: улицы
>   района Жулебино, но улицы Жулебина; живу в районе Жулебино, но живу в
>   Жулебине[5].  »
>
> В справочнике Т. Ф. Ивановой и Т. А. Черкасовой «Русская речь в
>   эфире»[9] обращается «    особое внимание на то, что славянские названия
>   среднего рода городов и местностей, например: Болдино, Колпино,
>   Бородино, Дулёво, Сараево, Косово, Тырново и подобные — склоняются по
>   общему правилу. Не склоняются лишь некоторые славянские названия
>   населённых пунктов, расположенных на территории Белоруссии и Западной
>   Украины (Гродно, Ровно и подобные).

http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ruwiki/1575843

Да, Гродно и Ровно не склоняются, но не потому, что они в Белоруссии и Украине, а потому, что там нет притяжательных суффиксов-окончаний -ово/-ево и -ино. В результате слова выглядят иноязычными, наподобие Осло.

В остальном подпишусь под каждым словом.

Аргументация в отношении омонимичности форм меня не убеждает. Да мало ли каких проблем можно найти в русской грамматике? И что, ради этого потворствовать безграмотности?