# Вежливое обращение к двум министрам

Tags: грамотная-речь

С удовольствием "проштудировала" вопрос "Трое из Простоквашино".
 Мой вопрос возник из ссылки "*Alex_ander*"а [**петиция**](https://www.change.org/p/%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80-%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8B-%D1%80%D1%84-%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B0-%D0%B8-%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8):

**Уважаемый министр культуры РФ Владимир Ростиславович Мединский и министр образования и науки Дмитрий Викторович Ливанов!**

Как  ***правильно*** обратиться к двум министрам? Ведь в этом контексте уважаем только министр культуры РФ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Никак не надо. Или уж "**Уважаемые** Владимир Ростиславович и Дмитрий Викторович!". Перечислять должности и титулы ***при обращении*** даже в дипломатическом протоколе не принято.

А что за вопрос про Простоквашино?

[Нашел )))](https://www.change.org/p/%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80-%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8B-%D1%80%D1%84-%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B0-%D0%B8-%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8)

Ну для столь бредовой идеи "обращение" под стать. Или это в рубрику "Нарочно не придумаешь"?

Comment: Так и называется: "Трое из Простоквашино"

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова А что ссылку не дали нормальную? http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/430349

Comment: Я и там вам ответил. И тоже, естественно, не согласился. ))))

Comment: Немного растерялась из-за Вашей полемики. Я задала не (совсем) правильный вопрос? Или обращение к министрам не входит в" рамки" обсуждения на сайте?

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова  Нормальный вопрос. А какая полемика-то? С кем? С автором петиции? Нет, увольте. )))) Бредовая идея - законодательно закрепить неграмотность. И под стать ей оформление - от "обращения"  с перечислением титулов до самих адресатов. При чем тут министерство Культуры или Образования? В "спортлото" бы еще написал.  Под стать всему этому и единственное число при "уважаемых". А вообще я вас покидаю. Извините.

Comment: "Нарочно не придумаешь" - это не ко мне...  На петицию  "из Простоквашино" ссылались специалисты, ее цитировали и предлагали к обсуждению.  Все смотрели вглубь ( в  -ено,  -ино,  -ыно),  а "шапку" -то никто и не приметил.  Да кому она нужна?! Никто, кроме Вас, не посчитал нужным поучаствовать в  обсуждении.  Странно...

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова "в рубрику" - это вся петиция. Насчет "странно" - тут такое наблюдение, что на суть вопросов перестали вообще внимание обращать.