# Склонение названия Протвино

Tags: склонение, ономастика

Судя по известным мне правилам русского языка, название города *Протвино* должно склоняться. Мне, как и многим протвинцам, это сильно режет слух (но это личное). И мне приводили много контраргументов. Разъясните, пожалуйста.

**Дополнение:** хотелось бы отметить, что название реки *Протва* - топоним неясного происхождения.

Википедия:

> Версию о славянском происхождении выдвинул В. А. Никонов, ссылаясь на
> наличие формы Поротва в духовных и договорных грамотах великих князей
> Руси XIV—XVI веков, но достоверных доводов представлено не было.
>
> Версию о связи этого гидронима с северо-восточным ареалом гидронимии
> на -ва (Лысьва, Сылва) предложил М. Фасмер. Однако этот ареал
> значительно отдалён от Подмосковья.
>
> Предпочтительнее представляется
> версия В. Н. Топорова о балтийском происхождении слова с
> соответствиями в прусском и литовском языках. В пользу этой версии
> говорит общность подмосковно-балтийского ареала гидронимов на -ва и
> упоминание в Лаврентьевской летописи о проживании в бассейне реки
> балтоязычного племени голядь.

Фасмер:

> Ср. авест. pǝrǝtu- м., ж., рǝšu- "проход, брод, мост", лат. portus,
> -ūs м. "гавань, убежище", роrtа "ворота, дверь", Portūnus "бог гаваней и ворот". Об этой группе слов (без русск.) см. Вальде–Гофм. 2, 343 и
> сл.

Comment: Думаю, для начала правильно "протвинец",  "протвинцам".

Comment: Что тут разъяснять-то? Почему Вам режет слух или что хотели сказать Ваши "контраргументаторы"? Ни того, ни другого мы не знаем. Склонять надо по правилам. Да, многие с ужасом ожидают когда "по просьбам трудящихся" придумают правила разрешающие не склонять русские слова, дело к тому идет, увы. Но пока этого не произошло.

Comment: По известному мне негласному, но действующему в радиоэфире правилу, Протвино не должно склоняться как ударяемое на последнюю О.

Comment: Об ударном окончании (забавная история).  Одна молодая барышня 5 лет тоже решила поучаствовать  в обсуждении темы. Ты где будешь жить - в Строгино или в Строгине? - В Строгино. - А вот некоторые люди говорят "в Строгине". -   В Строгине? Наверное, у них мозга нет.

Comment: @shampar Автор вопроса не "обозначил" ударение,  ведь возможно и ПрОтвино. Откуда же такая убежденность?  Сейчас мы все снова вернемся в Простоквашино,  а консенсуса как не было, так и не будет.

Comment: Вот он проснётся.., он конечно скажет.

Comment: Этимология данного топонима никак не влияет на его склоняемость, поэтому смысла в переоткрытии, на мой взгляд, нет.

Answer (score 0):

Все аргументы и контраргументы здесь, *в Простоквашине*:
[Трое из Простоквашино](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/430349/%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE)

Протв**ино** -  как раз  в этой темы.
 *Лично я считаю, что **склонять надо***,  придерживаясь особенностей и исключений,  указанных в дискуссии.
Посмотрите и принимайте решение сами.

P.S. А "протвинец", "протвинцы"  Вам слух не режет?  Но ведь с этим Вы соглашаетесь.