# Склонение сёл, — в селе Гришино или Гришине?

Tags: грамотная-речь, склонение, топонимика

В селе Гришино или в селе Гришине? в селе Войково или в селе Войкове? в селе Клепинино или в селе Клепинине? по-моему, искажается первоначальное название, если склонять.

Comment: Несть числа вопросам на эту тему. Вот последний из них:  http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/430349/%d0%a2%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%be

Comment: .... ну понятно, но как-то звучит по-дикому...

Comment: @М_Г используйте тревогу, чтобы отмечать дубликаты!

Answer (score 0):

Все приведенные вами названия склоняются. Наличие слов типа *город, деревня, село* никак не влияет на это: "В сел**е** Гришин**е**, в сел**е** Войков**е** и т. д.". Правила цитировались уже неоднократно, посмотрите в других ответах.